# Executing file in a vite project as a script

Tags: node.js, vite

I have a vite project in which I have a ts file, that I'd like to execute as a script.
This file uses special imports that are injected via vite plugins, namely

```js
import {env} from "$env/private/static";
import {browser, dev} from "$app/environment"
```

This special import can not be resolved without first going through the plugins that are configured for this vite project.

I tried executing the script with ts-node.
I've tried looking through the vite documentation, without finding something that solves this problem. One idea might be to generate an additional output file that is the bundled version of the script, but that seems like a quite heavy handed approach for something that seems rather simple, and the configuration that I would have to put into the vite config to accomplish this might again be overwritten by other plugins.

As a temporary solution right now, I'm using a vitest spec that imports the main function of the script, and executes it, but of course that's quite unstable and difficult to control.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. It's not as simple as I'd like it to be, but for my specific scenario will work just fine.

The simplest solution to getting another script as an output is to add it to the rollupOptions in the vite config file. However, the plugins that I'm using edit, and unfortunately overwrite these options, hence a more complex solution.
I ended up with this:

```js
export type ExtractScriptOption = {
    filename: string;
    id: string;
}

function extractScript({filename, id}: ExtractScriptOption): PluginOption {
    const nonce = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999);
    const scriptKey = `script/${nonce}/bundled`;
    return {
        name: "vite-extract-script",
        async config(config, env){
            (config.build?.rollupOptions?.input as Record<string, string>)[scriptKey] = filename;
        },
        async writeBundle(opts, bundle){
            const foundScriptKey = Object.keys(bundle).find( (key) => bundle[key].name === scriptKey);
            if(!foundScriptKey){
                return;
            }
            const scriptBundleResult = bundle[foundScriptKey];
            const manifestedScript = join(opts.dir ?? ".", scriptBundleResult.fileName);
            console.log("SCRIPTPATH_"+ id+"=" + manifestedScript);
        },
    };
}
```

This tiny plugin modifies the input section of the rollupOptions that are passed when bundling. This way an additional script is emitted, together with all other assets when performing a `vite build`.
By using the `writeBundle` hook at the bottom, the exact path of the script can be extracted and used further. I'm just console logging it and later get the path in a env variable using `grep` and `source` (as in `source <(npx vite build | grep SCRIPTPATH)`  )

As mentioned before, this solution is specific to my situation, and makes a lot of assumptions about the project.
What is clear is that there have to be `rollupOptions` created by vite or some plugin that is in use, and the input field has to already be an object, rather then a single string for a single import.

I'm still hoping someone will have a brighter idea, but this will work for me for now